# How to Transferring objects between windows forms in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i got a ListView in the windows form.When form loads ListView loading with personel objects. I want to do when some user double clicks on ListView , gets the personel object from the ListView.SelectedItem property and open a new form and transfer this object to newly opened form.

here is my codes for loading personel objects to ListView:

```
public static void GetAll(ListView list)
{
    list.Items.Clear();
    using (FirebirdEntityz context = new FirebirdEntityz())
    {
        ObjectQuery<PERSONEL> query = context.PERSONEL;
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            var mylist = new ListViewItem { Text = item.NAME };
            mylist.SubItems.Add(item.SURNAME);
            mylist.Tag = item;
            list.Items.Add(mylist);
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                     
    GetAll(listView1);
}
```

This is my personel object for transfer:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PERSONEL personel = (PERSONEL)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
}
```

Comment: I hope FirebirdEntityz should really be FirebirdEntityZ and not FirebirdEntities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new form that will be opened, add a new property in the form class;

```
private PERSONNEL Personnel{get; set;}
public ShowPersonnel(PERSONNEL _personnel){
   this.Personnel = _personnel;
   //do whatever you want here
}
```

In the main form;

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
        PERSONNEL personnel = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag as PERSONNEL;
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowPersonnel(personnel);
        form2.Show();

}
```

May include typos. Change PERSONNEL to PERSONEL.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably just add a public `PERSONEL` property to the form, which you would then set in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Then any code that has access to your selector form could access your custom selected `PERSONEL` property.

Answer (score 1):

- One way is to have a public propery
  as Factor Mystic has suggested.
- Or you could have a parametrized ctor
  and pass Personnel object. Although,
  this might create some problem with
  the design view of the form in Visual
  Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the display member of the listview control. Berfore you enter the for loop do something like:

```
list.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

Then bind the object.

```
list.DataSource = query.ToList()
```

The selected item will give you the object you've binded...

```
MessageBox.Show(((PERSONEL)list.SelectedItem).Name);
```

This was how it worked in .net 2.0. But I am sure there is probably a way to do this in 3.0 and greater...